# I have an error in my migration ETL in SSIS with a PostgreSQL data base

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, migration, odbc, etl

I need to migrate a postgreSQL data base for a SQL Server. It's all rigth with de columns, but when I start the ETL, after 20 minutes, the program show me an error:

> [Postgres [2]] Error: SQLSTATE: 08S01, Message: out of memory for
> query result server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably
> means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the
> request. ; The connection has been lost;

For contextualize, I'm doing this in a VM, connected by VPN in my client machine. This machine have 8GB RAM, and well, I can see that it's a problem, the migration is heavy, but can I have a solution in SSIS? Like a loop that divides the rows for sending?

I don't know if it can be a ODBC problem too...

I tried to change the `DefaultBufferMaxRows` and the `DefaultBufferSize`, but didn't work.

Oh, before start I'm receiving a message from SSIS:

> Postgres [2]: 'Row by Row' fetch method is enforced because the table
> has LOB column(s). Column ReturnValue is LOB

I don't know if it can be a piece for this problem.

Comment: Without a table spec, it's hard to say but yeah, you could segment your queries by "something efficient for the PG server" `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CreateDate >= '2023-06-20' and CreateDate < '2023-06-21'` A query like that and you enumerate through all the dates, or pull by a range of the primary key column(s), etc The [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help section can really help you identify the information that would improve your question.

Comment: I'm doing this by table name, in the moment i'm not using any query... Maybe can I integrate by query?

Comment: Under the covers, when you choose a table in the drop down, SSIS is going to send a `SELECT *`